# how to make sort function in javascript behave like mysql order by

Tags: javascript, mysql, sorting

I'm trying to sort a multidimensional array.
what should i put on the callback of javascript .sort() function to make it behave like mysql order by?

Example. 
Using mysql order by, result:

```
acx, 
acx abx,
acx acx,
S&P/ASX 20
```

Using sort function in js, result:

```
S&P/ASX 20,
acx, 
acx abx,
acx acx
```

Thank you.

Comment: Search for `[javascript] string sort case`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that sorting in JS is case-sensitive. To get around that, provide a function as an argument to [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), which should compare upper-cased (or lower-cased for that matter) versions of strings.

```
function cmp(x, y) {
    return x > y ? 1 : x < y ? -1 : 0;
}

a = ["S&P/ASX 20","acx", "acx abx","acx acx"]

a.sort(function(x, y) {
    return cmp(x.toUpperCase(), y.toUpperCase())
})
```

Comment: It works :) thanks a lot. i didn't figure out that the problem was just js is case sensitive. stupid me.

Comment: @user2020835: no problem )) BTW, sorts in mysql could be either way, depending of what collation you use.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what your multiple dimensions are, but your examples look like they're just sorted without case sensitivity.

In any case, to get custom behavior, what you do is pass a function into [`sort`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) that compares elements, returning -1, 1, or 0. So for instance:

```
yourArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

If you're comparing an array of arrays, within the comparison function, you'd compare the various entries in the two *arrays* you were given in `a` and `b`.