# Match MySQL's utf8_general_ci sorting order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, collation

I want to make sure that the order of data sorted with [JavaScript's `sort` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) matches MySQL's `ORDER BY` clause. I am using utf8_general_ci collation in MySQL.

Any ideas?

Update:

Compare the difference when I use JavaScript's `sort` method without the compare function

MySQL:

[image]

JavaScript:

[image]

To rephrase my question: I need a proper compare function I can supply to the `sort` method so it sorts in the same way as `ORDER BY` on a utf8_general_ci collation table.

Comment: Please provide a piece of code where you ran into your problem. This might be an xy-problem. You should explain, why you don't just use ordered mysql data. This could give you alternative approaches.

Comment: Have you already read the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator Explain as well why it is so important to have exactly the same order in JS.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631194/how-to-make-sort-function-in-javascript-behave-like-mysql-order-by something you are looking for?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell Yes, I need something like this. A proper compare function for JavaScript's `sort` method that sorts exactly in the same order as MySQL's `ORDER BY` on a  table with utf8_general_ci collation

Comment: According to the docs: `On character type columns, sorting—like all other comparison operations—is normally performed in a case-insensitive fashion.` My previous comment's link contains a method for such a comparison method

Comment: @ChrisSatchell Well, but how are you certain it's the same sorting algorithm as in MySQL's utf8_general_ci?

Comment: The safest way would be a real mysql sort requested via AJAX.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Are you joking?

Comment: It's a reasonable way in many situations. You deny explaining your intended purpose. So don't complain about common proposals.

Comment: @LukaszPrus I'm not, you'll have to try it. Maybe https://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/sorting-strings-with-accented-characters/ can put you on the right track

Comment: @ChrisSatchell Definitely not the same algorithm. I have already tried that. Thanks for the link but I need to be certain to have the same sorting method. Trying something out on a few sets of special characters doesn't satisfy me.

Comment: @ChrisSatchell Plus I am pretty sure that `localeCompare` isn't the way to go.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp says

"The locale is based on the language settings of the browser."

Comment: @LukaszPrus Agreed, I thought the `Intl` approach might help, but seems that's a dead end as well

Comment: @ChrisSatchell - Your first link deals with case folding, not accents.

Answer (score 1):

There is no collation in MySQL that puts `acute-o` before `A`, so I don't think it is possible.  And I would suggest that Javascript is 'wrong'.

For further discussion, please provide text pasted in, not images.  Also, try to provide the hex of the characters in question -- both from Javascript and from MySQL.

```
SELECT col, HEX(col), LENGTH(col), CHAR_LENGTH(col) FROM ...
```

and provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table in question.  There may be something wrong with the setup instead of the collation.

**Maybe**

It could be that Javascript is blindly comparing the "bytes", not the "characters".  This is how acute-o (a Western European character) could come before the Polish characters.  Another test -- add a couple of non-accented characters to your test case.  You may find that the come before even acute-o.

Adding `lz` to the test case will determine whether `lz < ł`, correct for Polish, but not the way utf8_general_ci works.  You should consider `utf8_polish_ci`.  To demonstrate the slash-l:

```
console.log(letterSort('de', ['a','z','ä', 'ł', 'lz', 'l', 'z', 'ó']));
console.log(letterSort('pl', ['a','z','ä', 'ł', 'lz', 'l', 'z', 'ó']));
console.log(['a','z','ä', 'ł', 'lz', 'l', 'z', 'ó'].sort());

> Array ["a", "ä", "l", "ł", "lz", "ó", "z", "z"]
> Array ["a", "ä", "l", "lz", "ł", "ó", "z", "z"]
> Array ["a", "l", "lz", "z", "z", "ä", "ó", "ł"]
```

In the last case, notice that all the accented characters come after "z".  This is probably equivalent to MySQL's `COLLATION utf8_bin`.

Comment: Yep the the Javascript .sort() sequence does looks like a "_bin" collation in MySQL.. Creating a MySQL table using `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_bin` gives this sorted sequence:  `A Z a l lz z ä ó ł`